# How to pass a VBScript variable to an iMacros Javascript macro?

Tags: javascript, macros, vbscript, imacros

I have a VBS script that looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim scriptName : scriptName = WScript.ScriptName
Dim cityPairFileNo : cityPairFileNo = Mid(Right(scriptName,5),1,1)

Dim iim1, i
set iim1 = CreateObject ("iMacros")

i = iim1.iimOpen("-fx", true)   
i = iim1.iimSet("cityPairFileNo",cityPairFileNo)
i = iim1.iimPlay("Test.js")
```

This VBS script runs the `Test.js` Javascript macro in Firefox:

```
var x = cityPairFileNo;
alert(x);
```

I just need to be able to pass/get the `cityPairFileNo` variable from the VBS script to the iMacros Javascript macro. For some reason `iimSet("cityPairFileNo",cityPairFileNo)` does not seem to work. I have also tried enclosing `{{cityPairFileNo}}` in double curly quotes in the Javascript, to no avail. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the script below could help you. Write down `Test.js` as follows:

```
iimPlayCode("SET !EXTRACT {{cityPairFileNo}}");
var x = iimGetExtract(1);
alert(x);
```

Comment: So you're basically writing the `cityPairFileNo` value to the `!EXTRACT` in an IIM macro that is played by the JS file, and then obtaining the value using the `iimGetExtract` command. I wonder whether using the `iimSet` command in the VBS script can pass the `cityPairFileNo` _through_ the JS to the IIM macro... I ended up just rewriting my JS script in VBS and passing the variable from one VBS script to another using `WScript.Arguments.Item(0)`.